# Form-data requests with Postman

Tags: node.js, express, postman, form-data

How can I send a Postman request using form-data?
If I try to use raw format works, but I need the form-data to send a image.

Here is my Postman request:
[image: Postman screenshot]

And my API
[image: API screenshot]

My server.js file has the following middlewares:

```
// Add middleware/settings/routes to express.
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use('/api', BaseRouter);
app.disable('etag');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you implemented the middleware to decode the binary file in Body at BE side?

If you're using ExpressJS. You can use the Lib `multer`

https://github.com/expressjs/multer

Answer (score 1):

Add `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` to the headers in Postman. And you should be able to send and receive an image normally.